# How to check whether at least one boolean is true?

Tags: java, boolean, guava

Given a array/list of booleans like:

```
Boolean a = true;
Boolean b = true;
Boolean c = false;
Boolean d = null;
```

I want to check if at least one of the booleans is true. So the sample shall count true=2 (a + b).

I tried guava style:

```
return Booleans.contains(
        new boolean[] {a, b, c, d}, true);
```

But resulted in a NPE.

Can you maybe point to a simpler solution?

Comment: "I tried guava style" note that the NPE has nothing to do with Guava: it results from constructing a `boolean[]` from `Boolean` elements, where the auto-unboxing of null elements results in NPE.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since any of the booleans can be null:

```
return Stream.of(a, b, c, d).anyMatch(Boolean.TRUE::equals);
```

or

```
return Arrays.asList(a, b, c, d).contains(Boolean.TRUE);
```

(You can't use `List.of` because that is null-intolerant)

If you want to write it in a more imperative style, define a method to check true-ness:

```
boolean isTrue(Boolean b) {
  return Boolean.TRUE.equals(b);
}
```

then invoke like

```
return isTrue(a) || isTrue(b) || isTrue(c) || isTrue(d);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a stream

```
return Stream.of(a,b,c,d).anyMatch(x -> x);
```

`Stream.of()` creates a new Stream of the four Booleans.
`anyMatch()` checks whether any of them satisfy the boolean predicate which is passed
Lastly, `x -> x` is a lamda which takes a Boolean and returns a Boolean. As we want to check whether `true` is one of the parameters, we can do this. This will take the element and return the element, which being a Boolean will be True, False or null. If it is true `anyMatch()` will also return true. If none of them are true(False or null) then it will return false,

Comment: "`x -> x` is a lamda which takes a Boolean and returns a Boolean" actually, it's a polyexpression, where in the context of an invocation of `Stream<Boolean>::anyMatch` it's a `Predicate<Boolean>`, meaning it takes a `Boolean` and returns a `boolean` whose value is `input.booleanValue()`, meaning it requires `input` to be non-null.

Comment: Oh alright, so it is the unboxing from `Boolean` to `boolean` which throws an NPE if tis `null`?